# pandas represent a holiday in time series data

Tags: python, pandas

***UPDATE 2*** - better question.

Would anyone know how to create one pandas dataframe ***column*** that represents a calendar ***holiday*** date as a 1 and a non-calendar ***holiday*** date as a zero?

TO make up some times series data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 


rows,cols = 8760,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
cal.rules


df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

first = str(df.first('1D').index.date[0])
last = str(df.last('1D').index.date[0])

pd.get_dummies(cal.holidays(start=first, end=last, return_name=True))
hols = pd.get_dummies(cal.holidays(start=first, end=last, return_name=True))

print(hols)
```

This prints for `hols`

```
            Christmas  Columbus Day  July 4th  Labor Day  \
2019-01-01          0             0         0          0   
2019-01-21          0             0         0          0   
2019-02-18          0             0         0          0   
2019-05-27          0             0         0          0   
2019-07-04          0             0         1          0   
2019-09-02          0             0         0          1   
2019-10-14          0             1         0          0   
2019-11-11          0             0         0          0   
2019-11-28          0             0         0          0   
2019-12-25          1             0         0          0
```

But if I try to combine all this into a single column with `numpy where` I get a pandas error.

```
df['holiday'] = np.where((hols['Christmas']==1) or (hols['Columbus Day']==1) or (hols['July 4th']==1) or (hols['Labor Day']==1) or (hols['Martin Luther King Jr. Day']==1) or (hols['Memorial Day']==1) or (hols['New Years Day']==1) or (hols['Presidents Day']==1) or (hols['Thanksgiving']==1) or (hols['Veterans Day']==1), 0, 1)
```

error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Would anyone have any ideas to try?

Comment: What do you want your single column to look like? Also your provided code does not run as is, can you update it to be a MRE?

Comment: what is MRE? mean?

Comment: I make an UPDATE to the post

Comment: I updated this does this seem like a better question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) option:

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
first = str(df.first('1D').index.date[0])
last = str(df.last('1D').index.date[0])
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
# Convert Holidays To DataFrame
hol = cal.holidays(start=first, end=last).rename('Holiday').to_frame()
# Set Value to 1 For Holidays
hol['Holiday'] = 1
# Join to DF
df = df.join(
    hol,
    on=df.index.to_period('D').astype('datetime64[ns]')
)

# Fillna with 0, convert to int
df['Holiday'] = df['Holiday'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df.head(25).to_string())
```

---

A [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) option:

```
hol = cal.holidays(start=first, end=last)

# np where with isin
df['Holiday'] = np.where(
    df.index.to_period('D').astype('datetime64[ns]').isin(hol),
    1, 0
)
```

`df.head(25).to_string()`:

```
                     Temperature     Value  Holiday
2019-01-01 00:00:00     0.771321  0.020752        1
2019-01-01 01:00:00     0.633648  0.748804        1
2019-01-01 02:00:00     0.498507  0.224797        1
2019-01-01 03:00:00     0.198063  0.760531        1
2019-01-01 04:00:00     0.169111  0.088340        1
2019-01-01 05:00:00     0.685360  0.953393        1
2019-01-01 06:00:00     0.003948  0.512192        1
2019-01-01 07:00:00     0.812621  0.612526        1
2019-01-01 08:00:00     0.721755  0.291876        1
2019-01-01 09:00:00     0.917774  0.714576        1
2019-01-01 10:00:00     0.542544  0.142170        1
2019-01-01 11:00:00     0.373341  0.674134        1
2019-01-01 12:00:00     0.441833  0.434014        1
2019-01-01 13:00:00     0.617767  0.513138        1
2019-01-01 14:00:00     0.650397  0.601039        1
2019-01-01 15:00:00     0.805223  0.521647        1
2019-01-01 16:00:00     0.908649  0.319236        1
2019-01-01 17:00:00     0.090459  0.300700        1
2019-01-01 18:00:00     0.113984  0.828681        1
2019-01-01 19:00:00     0.046896  0.626287        1
2019-01-01 20:00:00     0.547586  0.819287        1
2019-01-01 21:00:00     0.198948  0.856850        1
2019-01-01 22:00:00     0.351653  0.754648        1
2019-01-01 23:00:00     0.295962  0.883936        1
2019-01-02 00:00:00     0.325512  0.165016        0
```